# UPDATE and SELECT whit php on the same page how

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

I would like to do something that has always been possible with other languages, but with php I'm finding some difficulties ..
I would like the page in question, once loaded, to print all the values in the form that I created (with a SELECT) and that at the end of the form, through a button "CHANGE", when I click I go to do the UPDATE of all the data …

this is the structure of my table ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4voa.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
     header('location: ../../../index.php');
    }
    else
    {
 
?>
<html lang="en">

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "progettocantiere";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_progettocantiere";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$idCantiere = $_GET['idCantiere'];

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Cantiere WHERE idCantiere = '{$idCantiere}'";



    $result = $conn->query($sql1);


    $details = $result->fetch_array();




    $savedNomeCantiere = $details["nomeCantiere"];
    $savedCodiceCommessa = $details["codiceCommessa"];
    $savedIndirizzoCommessa = $details["indirizzoCommessa"];
 $savedComuneCommessa = $details["comuneCommessa"];
    $savedIndirizzoCantiere = $details["indirizzoCantiere"];
    $savedComuneCantiere = $details["comuneCantiere"];
    $savedOggettoDeiLavori = $details["oggettoDeiLavori"];
    $savedCommittente = $details["Committente"];
    $savedIndirizzoCommittente = $details["indirizzoCommittente"];
    $savedResponsabileDeiLavori = $details["responsabileDeiLavori"];
    $savedIndirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori = $details["indirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori"];
    $savedTelefonoResponsabileDeiLavori = $details["telefonoResponsabileDeiLavori"];
    $savedMailResponsabileDeiLavori = $details["mailResponsabileDeiLavori"];
    $savedDirettoreDeiLavori = $details["direttoreDeiLavori"];
    $savedIndirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori = $details["indirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori"];
    $savedTelefonoDirettoreDeiLavori = $details["telefonoDirettoreDeiLavori"];
    $savedMailDirettoreDeiLavori = $details["mailDirettoreDeiLavori"];
    $savedAssistente1 = $details["assistente1"];
    $savedIndirizzoAssistente1 = $details["indirizzoAssistente1"];
    $savedTelefonoAssistente1 = $details["telefonoAssistente1"];
    $savedMailAssistente1 = $details["mailAssistente1"];
    $savedCordinatoreProgettazzione = $details["cordinatoreProgettazzione"];
    $savedIndirizzoCordinatoreProgettazzione = $details["indirizzoCoordinatoreProgettazzione"];
    $savedTelefonoCordinatoreProgettazzione = $details["telefonoCoordinatoreProgettazzione"];
    $savedMailCordinatoreProgettazzione = $details["mailCoordinatoreProgettazzione"];
    $savedCoordinatoreEsecuzione = $details["coordinatoreEsecuzione"];
    $savedIndirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione = $details["indirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione"];
    $savedTelefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione = $details["telefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione"];
    $savedMailCoordinatoreEsecuzione = $details["mailCoordinatoreEsecuzione"];
    $savedAssistenteCSE1 = $details["assistenteCSE1"];
    $savedIndirizzoAssistenteCSE1 = $details["indirizzoAssistenteCSE1"];
    $savedTelefonoAssistenteCSE1 = $details["telefonoAssistenteCSE1"];
    $savedMailAssistenteCSE1 = $details["mailAssistenteCSE1"];
    $savedAffidatariaDeiLavori = $details["affidatariaDeiLavori"];
    $savedIndirizzoAffidatarioLavori = $details["indirizzoAffidatarioLavori"];
    $savedTelefonoAffidatarioLavori = $details["telefonoAffidatarioLavori"];
    $savedMailAffidatarioLavori = $details["mailAffidatarioLavori"];
    $savedFaxAffidatarioLavori = $details["faxAffidatarioLavori"];
    $savedpIvaAffidatarioLavori = $details["pIvaAffidatarioLavori"];
    $savedDatoreDiLavoro = $details["datoreLavoro"];
    $savedIndirizzoDatoreDiLavoro = $details["indirizzoDatoreDiLavoro"];
    $savedTelefonoDatoreDiLavoro = $details["telefonoDatoreDiLavoro"];
    $savedMailDatoreDiLavoro = $details["mailDatoreDiLavoro"];
    $savedRspp = $details["rspp"];
    $savedIndirizzoRspp = $details["indirizzzoRspp"];
    $savedTelefonoRspp = $details["telefonoRspp"];
 $savedMailRspp = $details["mailRspp"];
 $savedMedicoCompetente = $details["medicoCompetente"];
 $savedIndirizzoMedicoCompetente = $details["indirizzoMedicoCompetente"];
 $savedTelefonoMedicoCompetente = $details["telefonoMedicoCompetente"];
 $savedMailMedicoCompetente = $details["mailMedicoCompetente"];
 $savedDirettoreDiCantiere = $details["direttoreDiCantiere"];
 $savedIndirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere = $details["indirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere"];
 $savedTelefonoDirettoreDiCantiere = $details["telefonoDirettoreDiCantiere"];
 $savedMailDirettoreDiCantiere = $details["mailDirettoreDiCantiere"];
 $savedCapoCantiere = $details["capoCantiere"];
 $savedIndirizzoCapoCantiere = $details["indirizzoCapoCantiere"];
 $savedTelefonoCapoCantiere = $details["telefonoCapoCantiere"];
    $savedMailCapoCantiere = $details["mailCapoCantiere"];
 $savedAddettoAntincendio1 = $details["addettoAntincendio1"];
 $savedIndirizzoAddettoAntincendio1 = $details["indirizzoAddettoAntincendio1"];
 $savedTelefonoAddettoAntincendio1 = $details["telefonoAddettoAntincendio1"];
 $savedMailAddettoAntincendio1 = $details["mailAddettoAntincendio1"];
 $savedAddettoPrimoSoccorso1 = $details["addettoPrimoSoccorso1"];
 $savedTelefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1 = $details["telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1"];
 $savedIndirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1 = $details["indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1"];
 $savedMailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1 = $details["mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1"];
 $savedAspp = $details["aspp"];
 $savedTelefonoAspp = $details["telefonoAspp"];
    $savedIndirizzoAspp = $details["indirizzoAspp"];
 $savedMailAspp = $details["mailAspp"];
 $savedAddettoSicurezza1 = $details["addettoSicurezza1"];
 $savedTelefonoAddettoSicurezza1 = $details["telefonoAddettoSicurezza1"];
 $savedIndirizzoAddettoSicurezza1 = $details["indirizzoAddettoSicurezza1"];
 $savedMailAddettoSicurezza1 = $details["mailAddettoSicurezza1"];
 
                 
        



$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

echo($nomeCantiere);
  
  
  
  
  function updater($savedNomeCantiere,$savedCodiceCommessa,$savedComuneCantiere,$savedOggettoDeiLavori,$savedCommittente,$savedIndirizzoCommittente,$savedResponsabileDeiLavori,$savedIndirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori,$savedTelefonoResponsabileDeiLavori,$savedMailResponsabileDeiLavori,$savedDirettoreDeiLavori,$savedIndirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori,$savedTelefonoDirettoreDeiLavori,$savedMailDirettoreDeiLavori,$savedAssistente1,$savedIndirizzoAssistente1,$savedTelefonoAssistente1,$savedMailAssistente1,$savedCordinatoreProgettazzione,$savedIndirizzoCordinatoreProgettazzione,$savedTelefonoCordinatore,$savedCoordinaotoreEsecuzione,$savedIndirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione,$savedTelefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione,$savedMailCoordinatoreEsecuzione,$savedAssistenteCSE1,$savedTelefonoAssistenteCSE1,$savedMailAssistenteCSE1,$savedAffidatariaDeiLavori,$savedIndirizzoAffidatarioLavori,$savedTelefonoAffidatarioLavori,$savedMailAffidatarioLavori,$savedFaxAffidatarioLavori,$savedpIvaAffidatarioLavori,$savedDatoreDiLavoro,$savedIndirizzoDatoreDiLavoro,$savedTelefonoDatoreDiLavoro,$savedMailDatoreDiLavoro,$savedRspp,$savedIndirizzoRspp,$savedTelefonoRspp,$savedMailRspp,$savedMedicoCompetente,$savedIndirizzoMedicoCompetente,$savedTelefonoMedicoCompetente,$savedMailMedicoCompetente,$savedDirettoreDiCantiere,$savedIndirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere,$savedTelefonoDirettoreDiCantiere,$savedMailDirettoreDiCantiere,$savedCapoCantiere,$savedIndirizzoCapoCantiere,$savedTelefonoCapoCantiere,$savedMailCapoCantiere,$savedAddettoAntincendio1,$savedIndirizzoAddettoAntincendio1,$savedTelefonoAddettoAntincendio1,$mailAddettoAntincendio1,$savedAddettoPrimoSoccorso1,$savedIndirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1,$savedTelefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1,$savedMailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1,$savedAspp,$indirizzoAspp,$savedTelefonoAspp,$savedMailAspp,$savedAddettoSicurezza1,$savedIndirizzoAddettoSicurezza1,$savedTelefonoAddettoSicurezza1,$savedMailAddettoSicurezza1){
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli( 'localhost' , 'progettocantiere' , '' ,'my_progettocantiere' );
    $savedNomeCantiere =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$saveNomeCantiere);
    $savedCodiceCommessa =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedCodiceCommessa);
 $savedIndirizzoCantiere=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoCantiere);
 $savedComuneCantiere=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedComuneCantiere);
 $savedOggettoDeiLavori=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedOggettoDeiLavori);
 $savedCommittente=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedCommittente);
 $savedIndirizzoCommittente=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoCommittente);
 $savedResponsabileDeiLavori=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedResponsabileDeiLavori);
 $savedIndirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori);
 $savedTelefonoResponsabileDeiLavori=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoResponsabileDeiLavori);
 $savedMailResponsabileDeiLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailResponsabileDeiLavori);
 $savedDirettoreDeiLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedDirettoreDeiLavori);
 $savedIndirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori);
 $savedTelefonoDirettoreDeiLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoDirettoreDeiLavori);
 $savedMailDirettoreDeiLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailDirettoreDeiLavori);
 $savedAssistente1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedAssistente1);
 $savedIndirizzoAssistente1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoAssistente1);
 $savedTelefonoAssistente1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoAssistente1);
 $savedMailAssistente1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailAssistente1);
 $savedCordinatoreProgettazzione =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedCordinatoreProgettazzione);
 $savedIndirizzoCordinatoreProgettazzione=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoCordinatoreProgettazzione);
 $savedTelefonoCordinatore =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoCordinatore);
 $savedMailCordinatoreProgettazzione=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailCordinatoreProgettazzione);
 $savedCoordinaotoreEsecuzione =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedCoordinaotoreEsecuzione);
 $savedIndirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione);
 $savedTelefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione);
 $savedMailCoordinatoreEsecuzione =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailCoordinatoreEsecuzione);
 $savedAssistenteCSE1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedAssistenteCSE1);
 $savedTelefonoAssistenteCSE1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedAssistenteCSE1);
 $savedMailAssistenteCSE1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailAssistenteCSE1);
 $savedAffidatariaDeiLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedAffidatariaDeiLavori);
 $savedIndirizzoAffidatarioLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoAffidatarioLavori);
 $savedTelefonoAffidatarioLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoAffidatarioLavori);
 $savedMailAffidatarioLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailAffidatarioLavori);
 $savedFaxAffidatarioLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedFaxAffidatarioLavori);
 $savedpIvaAffidatarioLavori =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedpIvaAffidatarioLavori);
 $savedDatoreDiLavoro =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedDatoreDiLavoro);
 $savedIndirizzoDatoreDiLavoro =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoDatoreDiLavoro);
 $savedTelefonoDatoreDiLavoro =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoDatoreDiLavoro);
 $savedMailDatoreDiLavoro =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailDatoreDiLavoro);
 $savedRspp =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedRspp);
 $savedIndirizzoRspp =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoRspp);
 $savedTelefonoRspp =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoRspp);
 $savedMailRspp =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailRspp);
 $savedMedicoCompetente =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMedicoCompetente);
 $savedIndirizzoMedicoCompetente =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoMedicoCompetente);
 $savedTelefonoMedicoCompetente =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoMedicoCompetente);
 $savedMailMedicoCompetente =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailMedicoCompetente);
 $savedDirettoreCantiere =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedDirettoreCantiere);
 $savedIndirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere);
 $savedTelefonoDirettoreDiCantiere =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoDirettoreDiCantiere);
 $savedMailDirettoreDiCantiere =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedDirettoreDiCantiere);
 $savedCapoCantiere =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedCapoCantiere);
 $savedIndirizzoCapoCantiere =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedCapoCantiere);
 $savedAddettoAntincendio1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedAddettoAntincendio1);
 $savedIndirizzoAddettoAntincendio1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoAddettoAntincendio1);
 $savedTelefonoAddettoAntincendio1 =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoAddettoAntincendio1);
 $savedMailAddettoAntincendio1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailAddettoAntincendio1);
 $savedAspp =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedAspp);
 $savedTelefonoAspp=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoAspp);
 $savedMailAspp=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailAspp);
 $savedAddettoSicurezza1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedAddettoSicurezza1);
 $savedIndirizzoAddettoSicurezza1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedIndirizzoAddettoSicurezza1);
 $savedMailAddettoSicurezza1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedMailAddettoSicurezza1);
 $savedTelefonoAddettoSicurezza1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$savedTelefonoAddettoSicurezza1);
 
    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }   
   $sql ="UPDATE Cantiere SET nomeCantiere=[$savedNomeCantiere],
 codiceCommessa=[$savedCodiceCommessa],
 indirizzoCantiere=[$savedIndirizzoCantiere],
 comuneCantiere=[$savedComuneCantiere],
 oggettoDeiLavori=[$savedOggettoDeiLavori],
 Committente=[$savedCommittente],
 indirizzoCommittente=[$savedIndirizzoCommittente],
 responsabileDeiLavori=[$savedResponsabileDeiLavori],
 indirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori=[$savedIndirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori],
 telefonoResponsabileDeiLavori=[$savedTelefonoResponsabileDeiLavori],
 mailResponsabileDeiLavori=[$savedMailResponsabileDeiLavori],
 direttoreDeiLavori=[$savedDirettoreDeiLavori],
 indirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori=[$savedIndirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori],
 telefonoDirettoreDeiLavori=[$savedTelefonoDirettoreDeiLavori],
 mailDirettoreDeiLavori=[$savedMailDirettoreDeiLavori],
 assistente1=[$savedAssistente1],
 indirizzoAssistente1=[$savedIndirizzoAssistente1],
 telefonoAssistente1=[$savedTelefonoAssistente1],
 mailAssistente1=[$savedMailAssistente1],
 cordinatoreProgettazzione=[$savedCordinatoreProgettazzione],
 indirizzoCoordinatoreProgettazzione=[$savedIndirizzoCordinatoreProgettazzione],
 telefonoCoordinatoreProgettazzione=[$savedTelefonoCordinatore],
 mailCoordinatoreProgettazzione=[$savedMailCordinatoreProgettazzione],
 coordinatoreEsecuzione=[$savedCoordinaotoreEsecuzione],
 indirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione=[$savedIndirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione],
 telefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione=[$savedTelefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione],
 mailCoordinatoreEsecuzione=[$savedMailCoordinatoreEsecuzione],
 assistenteCSE1=[$savedAssistenteCSE1],
 telefonoAssistenteCSE1=[$savedTelefonoAssistenteCSE1],
 mailAssistenteCSE1=[$savedMailAssistenteCSE1],
 affidatariaDeiLavori=[$savedAffidatariaDeiLavori],
 indirizzoAffidatarioLavori=[$savedIndirizzoAffidatarioLavori],
 telefonoAffidatarioLavori=[$savedTelefonoAffidatarioLavori],
 mailAffidatarioLavori=[$savedMailAffidatarioLavori],
 faxAffidatarioLavori=[$savedFaxAffidatarioLavori],
 pIvaAffidatarioLavori=[$savedpIvaAffidatarioLavori],
 datoreLavoro=[$savedDatoreDiLavoro],
 indirizzoDatoreDiLavoro=[$savedIndirizzoDatoreDiLavoro],
 telefonoDatoreDiLavoro=[$savedTelefonoDatoreDiLavoro],
 mailDatoreDiLavoro=[$savedMailDatoreDiLavoro],
 rspp=[$savedRspp],indirizzzoRspp=[$savedIndirizzoRspp],
 telefonoRspp=[$savedTelefonoRspp],
 mailRspp=[$savedMailRspp],
 medicoCompetente=[$savedMedicoCompetente],
 indirizzoMedicoCompetente=[$savedIndirizzoMedicoCompetente],
 telefonoMedicoCompetente=[$savedTelefonoMedicoCompetente],
 mailMedicoCompetente=[$savedMailMedicoCompetente],
 direttoreDiCantiere=[$savedDirettoreDiCantiere],
 indirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere=[$savedIndirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere],
 telefonoDirettoreDiCantiere=[$savedTelefonoDirettoreDiCantiere],
 mailDirettoreDiCantiere=[$savedMailDirettoreDiCantiere],
 capoCantiere=[$savedCapoCantiere],
 indirizzoCapoCantiere=[$savedIndirizzoCapoCantiere],
 telefonoCapoCantiere=[$savedTelefonoCapoCantiere],
 mailCapoCantiere=[$savedMailCapoCantiere],
 addettoAntincendio1,[$savedAddettoAntincendio1],
 indirizzoAddettoAntincendio1=[$savedIndirizzoAddettoAntincendio1],
 telefonoAddettoAntincendio1=[$savedTelefonoAddettoAntincendio1],
 mailAddettoAntincendio1=[$mailAddettoAntincendio1],
 addettoPrimoSoccorso1=[$savedAddettoPrimoSoccorso1],
 indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1=[$savedIndirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1],
 telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1=[$savedTelefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1],
 mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1=[$savedMailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1],
 aspp=[$savedAspp],indirizzoAspp=[$indirizzoAspp],
 telefonoAspp=[$savedTelefonoAspp],
 mailAspp=[$savedMailAspp],
 addettoSicurezza1=[$savedAddettoSicurezza1],
 indirizzoAddettoSicurezza1=[$savedIndirizzoAddettoSicurezza1],
 telefonoAddettoSicurezza1=[$savedTelefonoAddettoSicurezza1],
 mailAddettoSicurezza1=[$savedMailAddettoSicurezza1] WHERE idCantiere = '{$idCantiere}'";
  
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       
  $message =  "Record updated successfully";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    } else {
  $conn->error;
  $message = error;
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
       
    }
    $conn->close();
 }   
  if(isset($_POST['savedNomeCantiere']))
  {
     updater($_POST['savedNomeCantiere'],$_POST['savedCodiceCommessa'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoCantiere'],$_POST['savedComuneCantiere'],$_POST['savedOggettoDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedCommittente'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoCommittente'],$_POST['savedResponsabileDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedTelefonoResponsabileDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedMailResponsabileDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedDirettoreDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedTelefonoDirettoreDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedMailDirettoreDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedAssistente1'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoAssistente1'],$_POST['savedTelefonoAssistente1'],$_POST['savedMailAssistente1'],$_POST['savedCordinatoreProgettazzione'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoCordinatoreProgettazzione'],$_POST['savedTelefonoCordinatore'],$_POST['savedMailCordinatoreProgettazzione'],$_POST['savedCoordinaotoreEsecuzione'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione'],$_POST['savedTelefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione'],$_POST['savedMailCoordinatoreEsecuzione'],$_POST['savedAssistenteCSE1'],$_POST['savedTelefonoAssistenteCSE1'],$_POST['savedMailAssistenteCSE1'],$_POST['savedAffidatariaDeiLavori'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoAffidatarioLavori'],$_POST['savedTelefonoAffidatarioLavori'],$_POST['savedMailAffidatarioLavori'],$_POST['savedFaxAffidatarioLavori'],$_POST['savedpIvaAffidatarioLavori'],$_POST['savedDatoreDiLavoro'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoDatoreDiLavoro'],$_POST['savedTelefonoDatoreDiLavoro'],$_POST['savedMailDatoreDiLavoro'],$_POST['savedRspp'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoRspp'],$_POST['savedTelefonoRspp'],$_POST['savedMailRspp'],$_POST['savedMedicoCompetente'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoMedicoCompetente'],$_POST['savedTelefonoMedicoCompetente'],$_POST['savedMailMedicoCompetente'],$_POST['savedDirettoreDiCantiere'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere'],$_POST['savedTelefonoDirettoreDiCantiere'],$_POST['savedMailDirettoreDiCantiere'],$_POST['savedCapoCantiere'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoCapoCantiere'],$_POST['savedTelefonoCapoCantiere'],$_POST['savedMailCapoCantiere'],$_POST['savedAddettoAntincendio1'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoAddettoAntincendio1'],$_POST['savedTelefonoAddettoAntincendio1'],$_POST['mailAddettoAntincendio1'],$_POST['savedAddettoPrimoSoccorso1'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1'],$_POST['savedTelefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1'],$_POST['savedMailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1'],$_POST['savedAspp'],$_POST['indirizzoAspp'],$_POST['savedTelefonoAspp'],$_POST['savedMailAspp'],$_POST['savedAddettoSicurezza1'],$_POST['savedIndirizzoAddettoSicurezza1'],$_POST['savedTelefonoAddettoSicurezza1'],$_POST['savedMailAddettoSicurezza1']);}

 
 /* 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "progettocantiere";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_progettocantiere";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



  $idCantiere = $_GET['idCantiere'];

    
  
 
    $result = $conn->query($sql1);
 */

?>
<h3>Cantiere</h3>
 <form method="POST" action="azioniContinua/inserisci.php">
    
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="3px"  class="table table-bordered" id="tab1" name="tab1" >
        <tr>
   <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
   <td colspan="12" width="2653" align="center" bgcolor="#B2E5FB"><strong align="center">ANAGRAFICA DI CANTIERE</strong></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
   <td bgcolor="#B2E5FB">Cantiere</td>
   <td colspan="11"><input type="text" name="nomeCantiere" id="nomeCantiere" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $savedNomeCantiere; ?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
   <td style=" border-style: none;"> </td>
   <td bgcolor="#B2E5FB">Codice Commessa</td>
   <td colspan="11"><input type="text" name="codiceCommessa" id="codiceCommessa" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $savedCodiceCommessa; ?>"/>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="submit" value="Modifica" href="modificaCantiere.php" class="btn btn-primary" />;
    </td>
    <td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../../paginaIniziale/azioniVisualizza/sceltaAffidatario.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere ?>">Continua -></a>
    </td>
   </tr>
         </tfoot>
 </table>
 </form>

  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the SELECT and UPDATE functions I have used .. but it does not work ...

I am attaching only a couple of lines of the table since otherwise it would be an infinite code ...

Sorry if the structure of the post is wrong, I am a beginner with stack ..

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that you're looking for a post variable called "savedNomeCantiere", however, your form doesn't have any fields that use that name. Make sure that all of the post variables you are looking for have named fields within your form that correspond to them.